# how to disable android headset/aux volume limit?

Tags: volume-control, media-player

While using my old Samsung Exhibit II 4G and now on my relatively new LG Nexus 4, I have noticed that music or media playback through headphones or auxiliary cable stops after about 30 or so seconds if the volume is higher than 3/4 of the max. Is this a bug? What seems even more confusing is that if you press play again, it stops the playback after less time (like 10-15 seconds) and continues to shorten the time it will play back until you lower the volume below 3/4. Can this be disabled? And what is it anyway? It is not app-specific and it doesn't care if I have the volume maxed out if I'm using bluetooth or the built-in speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds rather like something is overheating (hardware) especially the shorter times on repeated attempts. Presumably whatever that is is not in the speaker part of the circuit or when transmitting to bluetooth, but is specific to the headphone/aux jack part of the circuit.

So, probably a hardware bug (or "design flaw"), rather than a "limit" you can "disable."

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it is a hardware issue since I haven't seen any android that *didn't behave the same way, whether it was a Samsung or a Motorola or an LG.

Comment: @KG6ZVP On the contrary, I hadn't seen a single device that behaves as you described. One Samsung device I had gives a warning about going higher than 3/4th of volume, but doesn't prevent you from doing so anyway.

Comment: I experienced it on my Samsung Galaxy Exhibit and my Nexus 4